# Ember build failing

Tags: ember.js, npm, bower

I can't build my ember app, I get this error message. Tried

```
rm -rf node_modules bower_components dist tmp
```

And installed npm and bower again but it didn't work

```
The Broccoli Plugin: [SourceMapConcat: Concat: Vendor /assets/vendor.js] failed with:
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/home/ubuntu/workspace/qr-prototype/configtool-ember/tmp/source_map_concat-input_base_path-DgleBN9U.tmp/0/bower_components/keyboard/dist/js/jquery.keyboard.js'
at Error (native)
at Object.fs.statSync (fs.js:844:18)
at ConcatWithMaps.keyForFile (/home/ubuntu/workspace/qr-prototype/configtool-ember/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/broccoli-concat/node_modules/broccoli-caching-writer/index.js:90:20)
at Array.map (native)
at ConcatWithMaps.CachingWriter._conditionalBuild (/home/ubuntu/workspace/qr-prototype/configtool-ember/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/broccoli-concat/node_modules/broccoli-caching-writer/index.js:112:65)
at /home/ubuntu/workspace/qr-prototype/configtool-ember/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/broccoli-concat/node_modules/broccoli-caching-writer/node_modules/broccoli-plugin/read_compat.js:61:34
at lib$rsvp$$internal$$tryCatch (/home/ubuntu/workspace/qr-prototype/configtool-ember/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:1036:16)
at lib$rsvp$$internal$$invokeCallback (/home/ubuntu/workspace/qr-prototype/configtool-ember/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:1048:17)
at lib$rsvp$$internal$$publish (/home/ubuntu/workspace/qr-prototype/configtool-ember/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:1019:11)
at lib$rsvp$asap$$flush (/home/ubuntu/workspace/qr-prototype/configtool-ember/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:1198:9)

The broccoli plugin was instantiated at: 
at ConcatWithMaps.Plugin (/home/ubuntu/workspace/qr-prototype/configtool-ember/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/broccoli-concat/node_modules/broccoli-caching-writer/node_modules/broccoli-plugin/index.js:10:31)
at ConcatWithMaps.CachingWriter [as constructor] (/home/ubuntu/workspace/qr-prototype/configtool-ember/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/broccoli-concat/node_modules/broccoli-caching-writer/index.js:21:10)
at new ConcatWithMaps (/home/ubuntu/workspace/qr-prototype/configtool-ember/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/broccoli-concat/concat.js:22:17)
at module.exports (/home/ubuntu/workspace/qr-prototype/configtool-ember/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/broccoli-concat/index.js:26:10)
at EmberApp.concatFiles (/home/ubuntu/workspace/qr-prototype/configtool-ember/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app.js:329:10)
at EmberApp.javascript (/home/ubuntu/workspace/qr-prototype/configtool-ember/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app.js:1190:12)
at EmberApp.toArray (/home/ubuntu/workspace/qr-prototype/configtool-ember/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app.js:1542:10)
at EmberApp.toTree (/home/ubuntu/workspace/qr-prototype/configtool-ember/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app.js:1564:30)
at module.exports (/home/ubuntu/workspace/qr-prototype/configtool-ember/ember-cli-build.js:35:14)
at Class.module.exports.Task.extend.setupBroccoliBuilder (/home/ubuntu/workspace/qr-prototype/configtool-ember/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/models/builder.js:55:19)
```

Comment: add your "package.json" and "bower.json"

Comment: and ember-cli-build.js, too, please

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Solved It, I was importing some bower components on my `ember-cli-build.js` that weren't properly installed. I manually installed with `bower install keyboard` and it worked.

```
app.import('bower_components/keyboard/dist/js/jquery.keyboard.js');           
app.import('bower_components/keyboard/dist/css/keyboard.min.css');
app.import('bower_components/keyboard/dist/css/keyboard-previewkeyset.min.css');
app.import('bower_components/keyboard/dist/js/jquery.keyboard.extension-all.min.js');
```

Comment: Note for others: I encountered a similar problem that was ultimately being caused by a difference in case (`materialize` directory listed but actual name was `Materialize` and file system was case-sensitive)